# How can I implement aws chime realtime attendees presence?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I implement AWS Chime real-time attendees presence?

I tried to apply it in the Observer inside the videoTile and update the State, it works but when the videoTile is updated the state also gets updated, because the same name is shown several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is exactly what you want?
This is how you subscribe to realTimeAttendeesPresence:

```
    const attendeePresenceSet = new Set();
const callback = (presentAttendeeId, present) => {
  console.log(`Attendee ID: ${presentAttendeeId} Present: ${present}`);
  if (present) {
    attendeePresenceSet.add(presentAttendeeId);
  } else {
    attendeePresenceSet.delete(presentAttendeeId);
  }
};

meetingSession.audioVideo.realtimeSubscribeToAttendeeIdPresence(callback);
```